# Split a variable length string in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am having trouble to split a space delimited variable length string containing names in oracle 10g.Below are the few example of what I mean

```
1. Name : Alpha Beta 
   First_Name : Alpha
   Last_Name : Beta

2. Name : Alpha Beta Gamma
   First_Name : Alpha
   Middle_Name : Beta
   Last_Name : Gamma

3. Name : Alpha Beta Gamma Omega
   First_Name : Alpha
   Middle_Name : Beta
   Last_Name : Gamma Omega
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 10g? That's an *oldie*.

```
SQL> with test (id, name) as
  2    (select 0, 'Alpha'                  from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'Alpha Beta'             from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Alpha Beta Gamma'       from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Alpha Beta Gamma Omega' from dual
  6    )
  7  select id,
  8    substr(name, 1, case when instr(name, ' ') = 0 then length(name)
  9                         else instr(name, ' ') - 1
 10                    end
 11          ) first_name,
 12    --
 13    substr(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1,
 14                 instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(name, ' ') - 1
 15          ) middle_name,
 16    --
 17    case when instr(name, ' ') = 0 then null
 18         else substr(name, instr(name, ' ', 1, case when instr(name, ' ', 1, 2) = 0 then 1
 19                                                    else 2
 20                                               end) + 1)
 21    end last_name
 22  from test;

        ID FIRST_NAME      MIDDLE_NAME     LAST_NAME
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
         0 Alpha
         1 Alpha                           Beta
         2 Alpha           Beta            Gamma
         3 Alpha           Beta            Gamma Omega

SQL>
```

What does it do? Searches for spaces in `name` column and extract values as you described. Nothing special about it, except - perhaps - `last_name` which also has `case` expression. It checks whether the 2nd space exists or not; if not, substring after the 1st space is *last name*; otherwise, substring after the 2nd space is *last name*.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked

Comment: If the name contains only one word how can it be mapped to first name only .Right now it goes to last name

Comment: That's because you didn't say that there's such a possibility :) I edited the answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regular expression functions in Oracle DB **10g** version such as `REGEXP_INSTR()` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` :

```sql
WITH t(id,name) AS
 (SELECT 1,'Alpha Beta'
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'Alpha Beta Gamma'
    FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,'Alpha Beta Gamma Omega' FROM dual)
SELECT id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '([^ ]+)', 1, 1) AS First_Name,
       CASE
         WHEN LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name,' ')) > 1 THEN
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '([^ ]+)', 1, 2)
       END AS Middle_Name,
       CASE
         WHEN LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name,' ')) = 1 THEN
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '([^ ]+)', 1, 2)
         ELSE
          TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '(( .*)+)',REGEXP_INSTR(name, ' ',1,2),1))
       END AS Last_Name       
  FROM t
```

*Result set* :

| ID | FIRST_NAME | MIDDLE_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha |  | Beta |
| 2 | Alpha | Beta | Gamma |
| 3 | Alpha | Beta | Gamma Omega |

Comment: Thank you for the response.